# How to avoid css selector applying style rules from another file

Tags: css

I came across this problem while handling a large project and felt that i should seek an opinion from the community here.

I have specified a css class 'header' in style1.css, i.e.

```
.header { color: red;}
```

In another file, I inadvertently, named a class 'header' again with this rule :

```
.header { background-color: yellow; }
```

When i refreshed the browser i noticed the red font and after examining the style inspector found the problem. I tried to avoid the problem by applying specificity, i.e. #some-div .header, but that didnt stop it from applying the red font. Of course i could simply solve the problem by renaming header to something else, but i'm curious how developers who handle large projects handle this. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from your code, you specified values for different properties in the two declarations of the header class. The first declaration specifies a color property and the second specifies a background-color property. From all indications you're not really "overriding" anything since you didn't give conflicting values for one property so, CSS is simply giving the values of the first declaration of the header class to the second one because there's no difference. If you wanted to override it for the second you'd have to probably add a different identifier to the second declaration of the header class to point to a unique element and specify a different value for the color property. Hope this satisfied your curiosity.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at hand.

Comment: He said he wants to see how developers handle this kind of issue and I just told him how to handle it and why his problem occurred. What other answer am I supposed to provide?

Comment: He's asking how to avoid conflicts, not how to resolve them.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `!important` as another user suggested.  Avoid it all costs. It's the easy way out for the moment, but once you start going down that road, you're going to end up with a stylesheet that's terrible to manage.

Set your styles for a specific base and use classes and more specific selectors as overrides. Remember that stylesheets cascade.

For example, say you have a typical header font color that should be your `.header`.  If you have other one-off or unique headers that share same structure provide another class to that which makes sense to you.

**So as an example:**

Both headers have the `.header` styles but headers with the special class have blue text color which overrides red.

```css
.header {
  color: red;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
}
.header.special {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Regular Header</div>
<div class="special header">Special Header</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a different class to one of the cases. For example:

```css
.header {
  color: red;
}

.header.yellow-bg {
  color: initial;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="header">Red header</h3>
<h3 class="header yellow-bg">Black/yellow header</h3>
```

The second declaration for `color` applies because it is more specific (2 classes > 1 class).